# if url is AllItems.aspx then display none else AllItems.aspx?ID= display block

Tags: jquery

the script below doesn't seem to work!

what's wrong with it?

here is what i try to do:

if url is **AllItems.aspx** then display:none else **AllItems.aspx?ID=** display:block

```
var url = location.pathname;
  if (document.URL.indexOf("AllItems.aspx")>= 0)  {
  jQuery("#logo").css("display","none");
  }
    else if (document.URL.indexOf("AllItems.aspx?ID=")>= 0)  {
  jQuery("#logo").css("display","block");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ?xxx part of URL can be read by `location.search`, thus the code may be:

```
if (location.search.length <= 1) { // may be only a '?'
    $('#logo').hide();
}
else {
    $('#logo').show();
}
```